# Snakemake : CalledProcessError when running BWA on multiple files

Tags: snakemake

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders that each contain .fastq files(s) that I would like to align to a genome. I am trying to create a snakemake workflow for it. First I access each sub-directory and the files in them using wildcards. Then I use the expand function to store all the paths to the files and write a rule to map the files to the genome. The code is as follows:

```
    from snakemake.io import glob_wildcards, expand
    import sys
    import os

    directories, files = glob_wildcards("data/samples/{dir}/{file}.fastq")
    print(directories, files)

    rule all:
        input:
             expand("data/samples/{dir}/{file}.fastq", zip, dir=directories, 
    file=files)

    rule bwa_map:
        input:
            G = "data/genome.fa",
            r1 = expand("data/samples/{dir}/{file}.fastq", zip, 
    dir=directories, file=files)
        output:
            r2 = expand("data/results/{dir}/{file}.bam", zip, dir=directories, 
    file=files)
        shell:
           "./bwa mem {input.G} {input.r1} | ./samtools sort -o - > {output.r2}"
```

However, when I execute this code as "snakemake bwa_map", I get the following error:

```
Error in job bwa_map while creating output files data/results/SRR5923/A.bam, data/results/SRR5924/B.bam, data/results/SRR5925/C.bam.
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 19 of /Users/rewatitappu/PycharmProjects/RNA-seq_Snakemake/Snakefile:
Command './bwa mem data/genome.fa data/samples/SRR5923/A.fastq data/samples/SRR5924/B.fastq data/samples/SRR5925/C.fastq | ./samtools sort -o - > data/results/SRR5923/A.bam data/results/SRR5924/B.bam data/results/SRR5925/C.bam' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/Users/rewatitappu/PycharmProjects/RNA-seq_Snakemake/Snakefile", line 19, in __rule_bwa_map
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
Removing output files of failed job bwa_map since they might be corrupted:
data/results/SRR5923/A.bam
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
```

Am I wrongly executing the snakemake command or could there be a problem with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that the error occurred at the execution of the following shell command:

```
./bwa mem data/genome.fa data/samples/SRR5923/A.fastq data/samples/SRR5924/B.fastq data/samples/SRR5925/C.fastq | ./samtools sort -o - > data/results/SRR5923/A.bam data/results/SRR5924/B.bam data/results/SRR5925/C.bam
```

The problem could be caused by the fact that you have two bam files as output.

You probably shouldn't use `expand` in the `bwa_map` rule. The expand already took place in the `all` rule.